# Mobx awkward case. if i console.log(userStore) then it updates component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I've made `userStore` to manage auth state. When firebase auth fetches auth data successfully, `userStore` actions to change `loading` property.

```
class userStore {
  constructor() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.login(user)
      this.loadingDone()
    })
  }

  @observable user
  @observable loading = true

  @computed get getUser() {
    return this.user
  }

  @computed get getLoading() {
    if (this.user) {
      return false
    }
    return this.loading
  }

  @action
  login(user) {
    this.user = user
  }

  @action
  logout() {
    this.user = null
  }

  @action
  loadingDone() {
    this.loading = false
    console.log(this.loading)
  }
}
```

Now i want to change my `PrivateRoute` component by `userStore.loading` property. But without `console.log(userStore.getLoading)` MOBX DOES NOT UPDATE COMPONENT.

```
@observer(['userStore'])
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, userStore } = this.props
    console.log(userStore.getLoading) # <- WHAT HAPPENS HERE?????
    return (
      <Route
        render={props =>
          userStore.getLoading ? (
            <div>getting auth...</div>
          ) : userStore.getUser ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I cannot understand default behavior of Mobx. Is it depends on `console.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobx detects the component change based on the property that you use in the component.

When you `console.log(userStore.getLoading)`,  mobx knows that your component depends on that, loading and rerendering your component when it changes.

The use of `userStore.getLoading` in the Route below does not count (probably due to it being defined in a different functional component). [This article may help](https://hackernoon.com/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254).

To make this work, you can split the component in Route to a separate component and give it the observer tag.